# Choosing variance from a paired data.

Tags: probability

In a random sample of three pupils,it is believed that the difference between the results in two tests is normally distributed with variance 16 marks. If the mean of T1 = 23 and Man of T2 = 30, what is the 95% confidence interval for the improvement in marks.

I am getting [-10.21, 24.21] but the answer is given as  [-11.1, 25.1]

My problem , i think could be the variance of mean difference , 7. Is it correct to say  Sx = 6.9280...

Comment: I read your question twice and I still don't understand it, could you rephrase it? What is T1/T2? What difference is taken exactly etc...

Comment: Sorry T1 , T2  are test 1 and test 2. The difference is for mean scores.

Comment: Could you explain how you got to $[-10.21, 24.21]$? It looks very wide to me but I may have misunderstood.

Comment: I  used t distribution with df =2. i.e v = n - 1. Mean difference = 30-23 = 7. so Tinterval 7+ T. SE. where variance = 6.9